# How to refresh EJB 2.1 entity bean after changes made by JDBC in the same transaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic11g, ejb-2.x, entity-bean

I am working with following code, with mixed EJB 2.1 entity beans and JDBC operations done in a single container-managed transactions in Weblogic WLS 11g:

```
Entity e = entityHome.findByPrimaryKey(entityId);
e.setFieldX(initalValueX);

// this performs complex analysis of data fetched by JDBC
// and performs update of row in database corresponding with entity e.
// Let say it sets newValueX on field X
recalculate(entityId, newValueX);

Entity entityUpdated = entityHome.findByPrimaryKey(entityId);
Object valueUpdatedX = entityUpdated.getFieldX();
```

I encountered here two problems:

1. Method `recalculate` did not see change made by setter on entity ejb.
2. Finding entity bean again after `recalculate` does not see the changes made by that method. For example `valueUpdatedX` is equal to `initialValueX`, but should be equal to `newValueX`.

**I managed to solve problem 1.** by adding a dummy finder before calling `recalculate`. Here is an annotation for that finder:

```
@ejb.finder
  signature="java.util.Collection findFlushEJBCache()"
  type="remote"
@wls.finder
  signature="java.util.Collection findFlushEJBCache()"
  load-state="True"
  where-clause="0=1"
  include-updates="true"
  finder-sql="SELECT ID FROM entity WHERE 0=1"
```

The trick is the `include-updates` flag. [WLS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13814/ejb_tuning.htm#PERFM257) says it is a way to ensure that all changes on currently used beans are sent to underlying datasource. So I do:

```
Entity e = entityHome.findByPrimaryKey(entityId);
e.setFieldX(initalValueX);
entityHome.findFlushEJBCache();

recalculate(entityId, newValueX);
```

And method `recalculate` sees new value of field X.

**How can I solve problem 2?** How to force WLS to reload the entity from underlying datasource to fetch fresh data, without rewriting `recalculate` method to use EJBs? How to tell WLS that given entity should be removed from cache (invalidated)?

Some research I already done on the subject:

- I think the root cause is that finder `findByPrimaryKey` takes data from EJB cache instead of reload it from datasource.
- I tried to use different finder with `include-updates` but with same effect.
- Removing fetching entity `e` and fetching only `entityUpdated` works and gets fresh data. Probably because there is nothing in cache, so data is retrieved from datasource. But this is unacceptable - I need operations on EJB both before and after `recalculate`.

Comment: Did you tried EntityManager.refresh() method?

Comment: No, but isn't EntityManager part of JPA / EJB 3.x specification? The app I work with uses EJB 2.1. I will try anyway.